# How to Call a javascript function when an event occurs in a page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a span with some value:

```
<li>Rent Collected: Euros <span id="rentTotal">2000</span></li>
```

I need the value to be update whenever user does any action in the page. Is there a way to do it without using `onclick` on all the elements?

Comment: Events bubble, so just use the document click handler and you should get what you want.

Comment: add [onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to related elements

Comment: @HendyTarnando I am trying to avoid adding onChange on all events.

Comment: @AresAvatar can you given an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is using form elements to enter info, the form.onchange event is pretty handy for recalculations like that.

If you are not using form elements but instead using just HTML and lots of onclick code ... then this is why you should be using form elements instead.